# Context is undefined in translation module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, i18next

I tried to add a call to an endpoint in order to get translation. I have like this :

```
const loadLocales = async () => {
const context = require.context('./locales', true);
const data = await ApiService.post(`${translationToolUrl}/gateway/translations`, { project: 'myProject' });
const messages = context.keys()
.map((key) => ({ key, locale: key.match(/[-a-z0-9_]+/i)[0] }))
.reduce((msgs, { key, locale }) => ({
  ...msgs,
  [locale]: extendMessages(context(key)),
}), {});
return { context, messages };
};

const { context, messages } = loadLocales();

i18n = new VueI18n({
   locale: 'en',
   fallbackLocale: 'en',
   silentFallbackWarn: true,
   messages,  
});

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept(context.id, () => {
  const { messages: newMessages } = loadLocales();
  Object.keys(newMessages)
    .filter((locale) => messages[locale] !== extendMessages(newMessages[locale]))
    .forEach((locale) => {
       const msgs = extendMessages(newMessages[locale]);
       messages[locale] = msgs;
       i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale, msgs);
     });
  });
  }
```

I added this request : `ApiService.post`. But I have the error `TypeError: context is undefined` droped at this line `module.hot.accept(context.id...`. Have you an idea how I can solve that ? My scope was to add this request in order to get translations from database and from .json files for now. I want to do a merge between both for now, in the feature I will get only from database but this will be done step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you trying to declare multiple `const` in the wrong way, independently of trying to declaring them twice. This shows in:

```
const { context, messages } = loadLocales();
```

This would couse `context` and `messages` to be `undefined`. This won´t give an error, as I replicated in a small example:

```
const {first, second} = 'Testing'
console.log(first)
console.log(second)
```

Both, `first` and `second`, will be `undefined`. If you try to declare multiple `const` at once, you need to do it this way:

```
const context = loadLocales(), messages = loadLocales();
```

Comment: The problem is linked to await and async I  guess.

Comment: @klsdskldsd Your error says `context is undefined`, which means what it says. And as you try to call `context` in `module.hot.accept(context.id,...` while it is undefined, you get this error.

Comment: thank you.  If I do like you said : `const context = loadLocales();
const messages = loadLocales();
console.log(messages);` I have in the console : `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`